# Width and precision format specifiers for printf

Tags: c

According to https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ the `printf` format specifier follows this prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

Regarding `width` the above-mentioned web page states:

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed
> is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces.
> The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

In the sample source code, as shown below, I have specified a `width` of 4 and a `precision` of 2, for printing the value of PI.  I was expecting the output to be padded by a single blank space, to meet the field width constraint of 4, since the precision is 2.  However, I am finding that the output is not padded by a single blank space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   printf ("PI:%4.2f\n", M_PI);
   // Outputs PI:3.14, and not
   // PI: 3.14
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `3.14` are 4 characters `3` `.` `1` `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Minimum number of characters to be printed

`3.14` was printed - that's 4 characters `3` `.` `1` `4`. If you want to print an additional space, that would be 5 characters   `3` `.` `1` `4` - so width 5.